# Is there a Jenkins plugin to add / edit a value in all jobs instead of modifying each job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

Is there a Jenkins plugin to add / edit a value in all jobs for a choice parameter instead of modifying each job.
To explain lets take an example as i have version numbers "3.1.0, 3.0.1, 3.0.0" and then we have a new version 4.0.0
So what i do today is add 4.0.0 in version for each job which is very time consuming. Instead if we can add it at one place and its applicable to all?

Answer (score 1):

Try cofiguration slicing plugin.
Easy to use, and perfectly solves your problem.
https://plugins.jenkins.io/configurationslicing/

Comment: I did download that but not able to find help for the problem i am facing, would you guide me on how to do it?

Comment: If you've doenloaded it, you find it under  'Manage Jenkins'. You shoose "Parameters" and then you see the choosable parameters and the jobs, that use it as it is written in the documentation I linked above. You just add 4.0.0  to version parameter,where you alredy have 3.0.0, 3.0.1 and 3.1.0 (You will have something like {3.0.0, 3.0.1, 3.1.0} {test1[version], test2[version]})

Comment: Not all slicing is equal ... some types of slices will actually save every job, not just the ones w/modified values. It also does not recognize if a job changed since slicing. w/over 6000 jobs, we have also encountered timeouts when that happens. Try groovy script instead.